# How to find the difference in days between two dates in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have stored the date as a string in my DB in this format (`dd-mm-yyyy`).

Here I want to check the difference in days between the current date and the date in DB.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function index()
{

    $domain_count = domain_details::get()->count();
    //var_dump($domain_data);
    $domain_alert = domain_details::
    where('domain_ex_date','>',date('j-m-y'))
    ->get();

    return view('home1')->with('domain_count' , $domain_count)
    ->with('domain_alert' , $domain_alert);
```

How do I achieve this? Is my approach right?

The above code shows 2016 is greater than 2017. I can see my logic is wrong but how do I change this?

Comment: does that give you the difference in days? i think its beter to use carbon, further explaining is requiered so ican provide some working code

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have your dates in a DATE column in a proper format, otherwise MySQL won't know how to calculate it. Since you don't, you'll have to convert it with `str_to_date`, passing in the raw command:

```
where(DB::raw("str_to_date('domain_ex_date','%d-%m-%Y')"),'>',date('Y-m-d'))
```